# English / Spanish parallels and confusion

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect, spanish

In general, I'm pretty confident and familiar about all typical uses of the past perfect tense. However, I noticed a compelling case while studying Spanish years ago. In Spanish, there's the pretérito pluscuamperfecto de indicativo tense, which is supposed to be used in similar cases. However, it can also be used in situations where a speaker wants to highlight how quickly an action has been performed. For example: 'Yo pedí un periódico y al poco rato ya me lo había traido'. In can be literally translated as 'I asked for a newspaper, and soon he had brought it to me'. Although, I feel like 'I asked for the newspaper, and soon he brought it to me' sounds more natural in English.

Well, I've always thought that it's something that solely relates to Spanish. Some weeks ago, however, I found another interesting case in English: 'I used to keep fit, but since I started working as an architect my lifestyle had become mostly sedentary.'

Is it OK to use the past perfect here? Or is it a grammar mistake and the present perfect has to be used instead?

Comment: No, you can't use Past Perfect as in your example. In fact, the only way I can see to introduce it there is to ***reverse*** the Simple Past / Past Perfect forms for the two verbs, but the isn't really a natural Past Perfect form of ***used to***, so it's always going to be a bit awkward and/or shift the meaning slightly: *I **had been used to keeping** fit, but since I started working as an architect my lifestyle **became** mostly sedentary*. For your earlier example, colloquially we we can add "immediacy" using Present Tense: *I ask for the paper and he **brings** it to me.*

Comment: Time reference (and hence surrounding context) is important in licensing temporal constructions. 'Then, about two years ago, I realised that I badly needed to lose weight and take better care of myself. I had used to keep fit, but since I had started working as an architect my lifestyle had become mostly sedentary' is correct if a little podgy. Dropping two _had_'s (†English often does this with the past perfect, fudging 'correspondence of "tenses" ') here is arguably an improvement, though I'd use 'starting'. †Clarity must not be compromised, though.

Comment: ...note that for my last example above, you wouldn't normally know if the speaker had said and/or intended ***asked*** rather than ***ask***. But in colloquial contexts it can be quite natural to switch from Simple Past to Present for effect: *I **told** him to go away and he **punches** me!* (perhaps with onomatopoeic ***Wham!*** interposed after ***and*** to make the tense shift even more natural.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Do you not agree with me that neither *I had been used to keeping fit*  nor *I had used to keep fit* are particularly good here? The former introduces unwanted allusions to "expectation", and the latter is just "awkward" - as per [this Quora post.](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-such-thing-as-had-used-to-as-in-I-had-used-to-think-otherwise-until-I-found-out) and many others.

Comment: @FF I wouldn't class them as ungrammatical, but I'd probably not backshift, on clumsiness grounds.